# Invalid ViewState error in Firefox when EnabledEventValidation is on

Tags: asp.net, firefox, viewstate, eventvalidation

I have a stable error that reproduces each time i hit **F5**:
[image: Error]

There are 2 grids (master-detail) and the error actually happens on **callback** that is raised by my client-code when focused-row-changed event occurs on main grid. Something like this:

```
    this.mainGrid.ClientSideEvents.FocusedRowChanged = string.Format(@"
                function(s, e) 
                {{
                        if (typeof({0}) != 'undefined')
                            {0}.PerformCallback(s.GetFocusedRowIndex());
                }}",
                this.detailsGrid.ClientInstanceName);
```

The bug only reproduces in **mozilla firefox**! (yep, **IE** is not under question, that's kinda strange =))

And very important thing: the bug only reproduces when event validation is on, that is:

```
... EnableEventValidation="false" %>   // no error in this case
```

I suggested that the reason is that callback gets fired before the necessary fields get loaded ( as i got it, event validation uses some hidden fields ), so i checked that using `setTimeout`:

```
this.mainGrid.ClientSideEvents.FocusedRowChanged = string.Format(@"
            function(s, e) 
            {{
                window.setTimeout(function () {{
                    if (typeof({0}) != 'undefined') {0}.PerformCallback(s.GetFocusedRowIndex());
                }}, 2000);
            }}",
            this.detailsGrid.ClientInstanceName);
```

But tat didn't help. 2 seconds pass, callback starts and i receive the error. 
It only occurs on refresh - no error is raised when the page is loaded first time.
Disabling rows-cache for grid also didn't help.
Need assistance! =))

Edit: here's the StackTrace

```
   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureEventValidationFieldLoaded()
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.solutions_cashcenter_stockmanagement_frames_takeintostorageordersviewframe_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Users\udod\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website\b07be668\e534e3ef\App_Web_jeqyhxze.10.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Edit2: '**EnsureEventValidationFieldLoaded**' - yes, i see this point, but...how could it not get loaded if i wait for 2 seconds???

Edit3: You might notice that this is not an **IIS** problem (127.0.0.1 ip on screenshot).

Edit: UP!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yesterday I run into the same error and found a similar problem here: http://sietch.net/ViewNewsItem.aspx?NewsItemID=185

my current workaround is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#__EVENTVALIDATION').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

it seems to work. But im still testing.

Comment: Man, thank you so much! I don't even imagine how did you find that out (i mean that article) because i've been looking for solution in web for whole day and no results) But that was really the reason that firefox autofills the hidden input. Again, thank you!

Comment: Idk if I can manually award a bounty to an answer, but I'll try tomorrow.